# What is the difference between the two declarations?

Tags: c, arrays

In this part of code what is difference between `char *lineptr[MAXLINES];` and 
`char *lineptr[]`?

```
char *lineptr[MAXLINES]; /* pointers to text lines */
char *alloc(int);
int readlines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
```

Comment: Can you make you question clearer ? difference between what and what ?

Comment: Some of them cannot be compared with others as they are completely different things

Comment: `char *lineptr[MAXLINES];` is allocate an array of `char*` of size `MAXLINES`.
`char *lineptr[]` is the same as above , but the compiler decides the size. You need initializer lists for this.
`char *alloc(int);` is a prototype of a function named `alloc` returning a `char*` and having a parameter of type `int`.
`int readlines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);` is also the prototype of a function returning an `int` and taking two parameters of types `char(*)[]` and `int`

Comment: the original program is at link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193411/pointer-arrays-chapter-5-6-example-in-the-c-programming-language. now please explain 
@CoolGuy

Answer (score 0):

`char *lineptr[MAXLINES];` means, that function is declaring pointer to an array of size `MAXLINES`.

`char *lineptr[]` - this code snippet gives base address of array, to read `nlines` from that array.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
char *lineptr[MAXLINES];
```

Defines an array of `char *` of length `MAXLINES`.

For a function declared like this:

```
int readlines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
```

The argument `char *lineptr[]` is equivalent to `char **lineptr`.  This is because when an array is passed to a function, it decays into a pointer to the first member of the array.

You can call this function like this:

```
char *lineptr[MAXLINES];
....
readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES);
```

The function argument is different from this:

```
char *lineptr[];
```

This syntax is invalid, because it declares an array of unspecified size without initializing it.  This on the other hand is valid:

```
char *lineptr[] = { "line1", "line2", "line3" };
```

In this case `lineptr` is an array of 3 elements, with the array length being determined by the initializer.